# We should be more watchful of 0-activity spam users

Tags: discussion, profile-page, spam

Today I was running some data queries in the data explorer and ran across some interesting user profiles.  In particular, I was looking to see whom of those who states their location said San Diego (where I live).

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/516379

- [LockTechs San Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6198171/locktechs-san-diego)
- [Personal Injury Lawyer San Die](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4716435/personal-injury-lawyer-san-die)
- [San Diego Immigration Lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4960271/san-diego-immigration-lawyer)
- [San Diego Bicycle Accident Law](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4661716/san-diego-bicycle-accident-law)
- [Motorcycle Accident Lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4733883/motorcycle-accident-lawyer)
- [San Diego Bicycle Accident Law](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4661445/san-diego-bicycle-accident-law)
- [San Diego Park Shuttle and Fly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5662602/san-diego-park-shuttle-and-fly)
- [TOTAL T CLINIC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3616132/total-t-clinic)
- [Wilda Noland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4705925/wilda-noland) (real estate broker)
- [Accident Lawyer San Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4658225/accident-lawyer-san-diego)
- [San Diego Car Accident Lawyers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4657493/san-diego-car-accident-lawyers)

And that's just searching for users located here with odd "user" names.  I wanted to give them the benefit of the doubt but, it's pretty clear they're not creating profiles to make any kind of contribution.  A lot of them created the profile and did nothing with it.  So I tried to look for some patterns.  They typically:

- Filled out the About Me section of their profile
- Was never really accessed after the account was created
- Doesn't have any visible post activity
- Included a url
- Included a phone number

This search was very interesting.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/516380/spam-profiles?Top=200&ActiveDays=30&CreatedMonthsAgo=1&HasPhone=1&HasUrl=1

Now I know the [appropriate course of action is to email the team directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users) since we cannot directly flag these users but I feel we need to raise some awareness amongst the community and get these profiles deleted.  Of course, not everyone that fits this pattern is a spammer. Certainly my query doesn't capture them all, there's definitely other patterns out there to look for.  But I think there's enough here that warrants some attention.

Comment: O M G . Ah well, I guess that's what you get when you have too many law school graduates....

Comment: If this was the only problem that arose from having too many law school graduates, the world would be a much better place, @pekka. :-) I'm not really sure why this is worth doing anything about. I mean, what, you got "spammed" when you went looking for "odd user names"? Users can create any account they want, and can put anything they want in their profile. They only become a problem when they actually start contributing spam to the site, and then the accounts will be destroyed.

Comment: I went over that list and none of these users have been detected by the [Smoke Detector](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=san+diego&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) which means that they either never posted actual spam or did so before [Smokey](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki) started watching the endless stream of spam that passed Spam Ram. That said: the profile is yours, you can advertize your product/company there. Just don't post spam answers or question.

Comment: I guess "check Stack Overflow spam profiles" is another entry for [this list](https://popehat.com/2016/07/18/cynicism-and-taking-clients-seriously/#comment-1344526) of how to choose a defense attorney

Comment: Nice digging! – You do realize you just made their spam effective? Nobody visits random user profiles, but if they're mentioned in a Meta post ...

Comment: I think the community has to develop a team that will need to find these spammers as you did and delete them.

Comment: I fixed a double negative in your post; please feel free to revert if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Don't those links have the `rel=“nofollow”` attribute (for low-reputation-points users)?

Comment: Do a user search for "lawyer" and you can find a bunch more. Which is great, because if I'm ever shopping around for lawyers, I now know exactly which ones *not* to use.

Comment: Wait, I need to get used to this feeling, something not about docs.so

Comment: @PeterMortensen As far as I can see, they aren't even links, just text.

Comment: @DanielEngel How are they spammers? They aren't hurting anything.

Comment: They're not doing themselves any good, either, as far as I can see.  As Peter said, those pages don't come up in Google searches.  Why do they bother?

Comment: @AlanMoore The URLs they in their profile aren't links, but the pages will still show up on Google with the right search terms. There's nothing to prevent them from being indexed.