# Possible spam accounts

Tags: discussion, profile-page, spam, accounts

While browsing through the new users page I noticed this (note the "Download Link:" text in almost all of them):

> [image]

Each of those profiles contains something like this, with links for

> [image]

:

> [image]

Should these be deleted, ignored, or something else?

EDIT: can currently be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=180&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate)

Comment: Duct tape parenting? That one sounds intriguing...

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w

Comment: I'm actually disappointed. I googled the cover and the tape is not where I imagined it would be. @yivi

Comment: Just another successful new-user initiative! Site growth is setting new records.

Comment: Duck tape parenting .. I use duck tape for my pet but never thought about kidz..

Comment: babycakes13 bothers me the most

Comment: I also noticed that all of them have an about me of the form "DOWNLOAD - (something) - in digital format" and that their website is of the form `iwlbooks.com/download?i=(some numbers)`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9028550/joshua-carter) is an example.

Comment: @JonClements: or even here: *cough* [We should be more watchful of 0-activity spam users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329251) *cough*

Comment: [This SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/766141/find-spam-account) gives that there are more than 11k spam account like this

Comment: [Another SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/766142/number-spam-account-creation-per-day) for the number of creation per day of those spam accounts