# Spam in Stack Exchange profiles fed through Google Alerts

Tags: discussion, profile-page, spam

Due to the sites I maintain I have a Google Alert on the keyword 'testosterone'.

So earlier I get the daily email and there's an entry for Shred FX Testosterone booster.

[image]

Click on it and it's this profile;

https://stackexchange.com/users/12442112/shred-fx-testosterone

It was only set up yesterday, so I don't see it appearing in the normal Google serps, but I'm quite sure it will.

With a site as big and powerful as Stack Overflow, and a meta title like `User Shred FX Testosterone - Stack Exchange` plus the keyword stuffed user profile then I'm sure it would rank and the URL that they've added to the profile get some traffic.

I suppose if I was to make this a feature request it would be to ensure that profiles get set to `noindex` until the user has achieved a sufficient rep score.

I'm not sure if `noindex` also prevents a site from appearing in the Google Alerts feed too; I found an unanswered questions on it here [Can "noindex" on a post prevent Google Alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882905/can-noindex-on-a-post-prevent-google-alert), but nothing concrete.

**Edit**

Next day - he's amongst the tumbleweed on my Page 4, but 'Shred Fx Testosterone' will be a very competitive term. I'll be curious to see how/if his ranking increases ... assuming his profile doesn't get nuked by the moderators of course.

[image]

Comment: MSE duplicate: [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w)

Comment: Thanks @Stijn - yes same (and very recent) discussion.  I can't seem to close it as that dupe as it's not on this site though, but for sure it 's a dupe of that.

Comment: I love the URL. I would be highly suspicious of something that had to be specifically advertised as a "legal health product".

Comment: @Ben When your target demographic has only one question "Is this stuff even legal?", you put it right in the name.

Comment: @Ben reminds me of my favorite restaurant, Fully Cooked Chicken

Comment: I say the user should be banned - what kind of user is that?

Comment: @Stijn this adds a very relevant factor: the spam profiles are actually visible through Google alerts, not only on the new users overview. That means they're probably generating more views than I previously expected.

Comment: Ah, yeah, Shred. That's some good stuff. BRB, impregnating Charleston.

Comment: [Screenshot of user profile for context](http://i.thinimg.com/img/21xc.png), since it'll get nuked at some point.

Comment: Interestingly that's a user both us regular meaty users and smokedetector have been nuking regularly. Its *curious* that they started profile spamming too, but now that SO knows, they can deal with it with along with our insurance and finance and streaming spammers ^^

Comment: @Stijn comments in that MSE post also refer to related post here at MSO: [Possible spam accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360042/839601)

Comment: @souldeux This Drink Is Not Poison (Red Cherry Flavor)

Comment: Isn't it an idea to hide new accounts from Google until they've reached 25 rep or something?

Comment: "without any side effects" ... other than relentless spam, of course.  You sell your digital soul to the Father of Spam by taking this supplement.

Comment: How else am I supposed to find sellers of fine discount gucci handbags for my wife? If I have to resort to buying them legally, I won't be able to afford groceries for my family. Do you want my family to starve?

Comment: Why is there no "Flag Profile" capability?  Should this be a feature request?